# ActionScript 3 - Passing parameter to an addEventListener

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, tween

This is my code:

```
function switchText(evt, newText:String, time=5) {
    var fadeTextTween:Tween = new Tween(evt, "alpha", Regular.easeIn, evt.alpha, 0, time, false);
    fadeTextTween.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, textTweenEnd);

}

function textTweenEnd(e:TweenEvent) {
    e.target.obj.text=newText;
}
```

I want to access the newText parameter from within textTweenEnd. How do I pass newText as a parameter to the textTweenEnd function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass any additional parameters to `motion finish` handler, so you need to implement some additional logic to bind tweened object with future text.

I would recommend to use TweenLite, with `onComplete` and `onCompleteParams` properties.

```
function switchText(evt:TextField, alpha:Number, newText:String, time:Number = 5):void {
    TweenLite.to(evt, time, {alpha: alpha, onComplete: updateText, onCompleteParams: [evt, newText]});
}

function updateText(textField: TextField, value:String):void {
    textField.text = value;
}
```

Comment: I also highly recommend using TweenLite ([GSAP](http://www.greensock.com/v12/)). Click that link and download the AS3 version.